# why is exchange failing outbound smtp test?

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, exchange-2010

I am using https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com to test outbound smtp connectivity. I am getting this message at the last stage:

```
Attempting to find the SPF record using a DNS TEXT record query.
ExRCA wasn't able to find the SPF record.

Additional Details
No records were found.
```

We have Exchange 2010. The test was working until I rebooted our AD (Windows Server 2003). Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with your Exchange server, but your DNS. Somehow you lost your SPF record when you rebooted.

In a nutshell, you want a TXT record on your domain (example.com, if that's you.  Nothing to the left of the domain name) that specifies who can send email as your domain. You probably want something like "v=spf1 a mx -all" (read: whatever has an a record from example.com or an mx, they can send as me. The "~all" means "but I'm not sure, so don't automatically fail others", which is a nice safety while you're working on it.)